# What is the difference between Tensorflow and Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am currently working with neural networks in keras and I know that it works with tensorflow in the back-end, I have it installed on the GPU, but I don't know if keras uses the GPU or if it is something completely different from tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow is a mid-level framework that performs operations on tensors. Keras is a high-level API that simplifies the creation and training of neural networks. Keras doesn't do any of the tensor ops itself; it delegates those to its backend, which is a mid-level framework of your choosing: TensorFlow, CNTK, or Theano. Each of those frameworks can be configured to do the tensor ops in whatever ways they can (as far as I am aware, each of them can use either CPUs or GPUs). Keras, however, doesn't really care how the ops get done. It just tells the backend to do them, and they get done.